# How use jwt for keep 100 % secure your app (flutter and php)

Tags: flutter, jwt

For secure my app i use jwt. When a user log in i create a secure jwt and send it to php scripts. For the moment i create a jwt with huge duration of life which is not very secure because someone can steal it and try to use it for contact my php scripts. I store jwt on mobile too so when user launch app it uses the jwt and send it to php api. What is for you the best way for use jwt for best security. Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve it?